# Matching a pattern in String

Tags: java, regex, string

Dont know how to ask more correctly, so will try as I can.

There is one example string where we are searching and another pattern String:

- it's length == 3,
- first character is 'b',
- third character is also 'b'.

I need some way to figure out if example contains pattern (it comes to my mind something like example.indexOf(pattern) > - 1)

```
Pattern = "b*b"
Example = "gjsdng" - false;
Example = "bob" - true;
Example = "bab" - true;
Example = "gdfgbUbfg" - true;
```

Comment: string.contains() might be what you're looking for

Comment: you may want to start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: String.matches was what I was looking for

Comment: `string.contains()` doesn't support regex pattern.

Comment: @EdisonMiranda, consider accepting the answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String#matches(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method with `.*?b.b.*` regex pattern to match the text.

```
System.out.println("gjsdng".matches(".*?b.b.*"));    //false
System.out.println("bob".matches(".*?b.b.*"));       //true
System.out.println("bab".matches(".*?b.b.*"));       //true
System.out.println("gdfgbUbfg".matches(".*?b.b.*")); // true
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
  b                        'b'
  .                        any character except \n
  b                        'b'
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: You should just be able to do `b.b`, since you aren't matching the whole string w/anchors.

Comment: @Sam `String.matches` looks for whole string. Try it at your end.

Answer (score 0):

`.*b[A-Za-z]b.*` is the regex pattern you are looking for.

- `b` letter `b` in character 1 of pattern
- `[A-Za-z]` any letter A-Z or a-z in character 2 of pattern
- `b` letter `b` in character 3 of pattern

  ```
  System.out.println("bobby".matches(".*b[A-Za-z]b.*")); // true
  System.out.println("gjsdng".matches(".*b[A-Za-z]b.*")); // false
  System.out.println("bob".matches(".*b[A-Za-z]b.*")); // true
  System.out.println("bab".matches(".*b[A-Za-z]b.*")); // true
  System.out.println("gdfgbUbfg".matches(".*b[A-Za-z]b.*")); // true
  ```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: `gdfgbUbfg` should be `true` (OP didn't have the best explanation, imo).

Comment: I believe `^` is wrong there: his b.b does not have to be at the beginning (see the last example)

Answer (score 0):

Brrrrr.

There is absolutely no need to create the `Pattern` multiple times. Just compile it once:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "b.b" );
```

Furthermore there is no need to match the whole String. Just to find one occurrence of the searched String. So this is what you're looking for:

```
assertFalse( pattern.matcher( "Gollum" ).find() );
assertTrue( pattern.matcher( "bob" ).find() );
assertTrue( pattern.matcher( "babe" ).find() );
assertTrue( pattern.matcher( "Alibaba" ).find() );
```